# Differential driven robot warping when driving forward and stuttering when driving backwards

Tags: differential-drive, gazebo-2.2, ubuntu-14.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'm modelling a differential driven robot and have two problems.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

My first problem: The robot turns a bit right or left when I want to drive forward.

Made this short [Video](https://youtu.be/CMZoc8L9fHw) for explanation.

I tried to fix it by setting the wheels stiffness, damping, friction, maxVel and minDepth to different values but didn't get it working correctly.

This are my xxx.urdf.xacro files:

body.urdf.xacro:

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
 
  <!-- The body macro that is also used to generate the tail -->
  <xacro:macro name="body" params="name parent length width height mass off_x off_y off_z role pitch yaw type full_joint material Gmaterial mu1 mu2 kp kd">
   
    <!-- if -->
    <xacro:if value="${full_joint}">
      <joint name="${parent}_to_${name}" type="${type}">
        <parent link="${parent}"/>
        <child link="${name}_body_link"/>
        <origin rpy= "${role} ${pitch} ${yaw}" xyz="${off_x} ${off_y} ${off_z}"/>
      </joint>
    </xacro:if>
 
    <!-- else -->
    <xacro:unless value="${full_joint}">
      <joint name="${parent}_to_${name}" type="${type}">
        <parent link="${parent}"/>
        <child link="${name}_body_link"/>
      </joint>
    </xacro:unless>
 
    <link name="${name}_body_link">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
           <box size="${length} ${width} ${height}"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="${material}"/>
       </visual>
 
       <collision>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
         <geometry>
           <box size="${length} ${width} ${height}"/>
         </geometry>
       </collision>
 
       <xacro:solid_cuboid_inertial
        width="${length}" depth="${width}"
        height="${height}" mass="${mass}">
        <origin xyz="${off_x} ${off_y} ${off_z}"/>
      </xacro:solid_cuboid_inertial>
    </link>
 
    <gazebo reference="${name}_body_link">
      <!-- <material>Gazebo/Black</material> -->
      <material>Gazebo/${Gmaterial}</material>
      <mu1>${mu1}</mu1>
      <mu2>${mu2}</mu2>
      <kp>${kp}</kp>
      <kd>${kd}</kd>
    </gazebo>
    <!--
   <gazebo reference="{parent}_to_${name}" >
   </gazebo>
   -->
  </xacro:macro>
 
  <!-- The sphere macro that is used to simulate the finn -->
  <xacro:macro name="finn" params="name parent reflect radius mass off_x off_y off_z role pitch yaw type material Gmaterial mu1 mu2 kp kd maxVel minDepth fdir1">
   
    <joint name="${parent}_to_${name}" type="${type}">
      <parent link="${parent}"/>
      <child link="${name}_sphere_link"/>
      <origin rpy= "${role} ${pitch} ${yaw}" xyz="${off_x} ${off_y} ${reflect * off_z}"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
 
    <link name="${name}_sphere_link">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
           <sphere radius="${radius}"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="${material}"/>
       </visual>
 
       <collision>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
         <geometry>
           <sphere radius="${radius}"/>
         </geometry>
       </collision>
 
       <xacro:sphere_inertial
        radius="${radius}" mass="${mass}">
        <origin xyz="${off_x} ${off_y} ${reflect * off_z}"/>
      </xacro:sphere_inertial>
    </link>
 
    <gazebo reference="${name}_sphere_link">
      <!-- <material>Gazebo/Black</material> -->
      <material>Gazebo/${Gmaterial}</material>
      <mu1>${mu1}</mu1>
      <mu2>${mu2}</mu2>
      <kp>${kp}</kp>
      <kd>${kd}</kd>
      <maxVel>${maxVel}</maxVel>
      <minDepth>${minDepth}</minDepth>
      <fdir1>${fdir1}</fdir1>
    </gazebo>
 
    <gazebo reference="{parent}_to_${name}" >
      <kp>${kp}</kp>
      <kd>${kd}</kd>
    </gazebo>
 
  </xacro:macro>
 
 
  <!-- Definitions of all single parts -->
  <xacro:body
       name="main"
       parent="base_link"
       length="0.14"
       width="0.22"
       height="0.09"
       mass="1.709"
       off_x="0"
       off_y="0"
       off_z="0"
        role="0"
        pitch="0"
        yaw="0"
       type="fixed"
       full_joint="false"
       material="body_mat"
       Gmaterial="Black"
        mu1="0.5"
        mu2="50.0"
        kp="100000000.0"
        kd="1.0"
 />
 
  <!-- off_x = half body + half tail-->
  <xacro:body
       name="tail"
       parent="main_body_link"
       length="0.22"
       width="0.10"
       height="0.02"
       mass="0.242"
       off_x="${-0.11-0.07}"
       off_y="0"
       off_z="0"
       role="0"
       pitch="0"
       yaw="0"
       type="fixed"
       full_joint="true"
       material="tail_mat"
       Gmaterial="Black"
       mu1="0.5"
       mu2="50.0"
       kp="100000000.0"
       kd="1.0"
 
 />
 
  <xacro:finn
       name="upper_finn"
       parent="main_body_link"
        reflect="1"
       radius="0.01"
       mass="0.050"
       off_x="${-0.07-0.165}"
       off_y="0"
       off_z="${0.055-0.01}"
       role="${PI/2}"
       pitch="0"
       yaw="0"
       type="fixed"
       material="u_sphere_mat"
       Gmaterial="Orange"
       mu1="0"
       mu2="0"
       kp="10000000"
       kd="1"
       maxVel="1000"
       minDepth="0"
       fdir1="0 0 1"
 />
 
  <xacro:finn
       name="lower_finn"
       parent="main_body_link"
       reflect="-1"
       radius="0.01"
       mass="0.050"
       off_x="${-0.07-0.165}"
       off_y="0"
       off_z="${0.055-0.01}"
       role="${PI/2}"
       pitch="0"
       yaw="0"
       type="fixed"
       material="l_sphere_mat"
       Gmaterial="Blue"
       mu1="0"
       mu2="0"
       kp="10000000"
       kd="1"
       maxVel="1000"
       minDepth="0"
       fdir1="0 0 1"
 
 />
 
</robot>
```

wheel.urdf.xacro:

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
 
  <!-- The "wheel" macro defines a wheel. -->
  <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="name parent reflect length radius mass off_x off_y off_z role pitch yaw type material Gmaterial mu1 mu2 kp kd maxVel minDepth fdir1">
 
    <joint name="${parent}_to_${name}_wheel_joint" type="${type}">
      <parent link="${parent}"/>
      <child link="${name}_wheel_link"/>
      <origin rpy= "${role} ${pitch} ${yaw}" xyz="${off_x} ${reflect*off_y} ${off_z}"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>      
      <dynamics damping="0.1" friction="100.0"/>
      <!-- <dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0" spring_stiffness="1" /> -->
      <!-- <limit effort="100" velocity="100" /> -->
    </joint>
 
    <link name="${name}_wheel_link">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${radius}" length="${length}"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="${material}"/>
      </visual>
 
      <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${radius}" length="${length}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
 
      <xacro:wheel_inertial
         rad="${radius}" height="${length}" mass="${mass}">
          <origin rpy="${PI/2} 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      </xacro:wheel_inertial>
    </link>
   
    <gazebo reference="${name}_wheel_link">
      <!-- <material>Gazebo/Black</material> -->
      <material>Gazebo/${Gmaterial}</material>
      <mu1>${mu1}</mu1>
      <mu2>${mu2}</mu2>
      <kp>${kp}</kp>
      <kd>${kd}</kd>
      <maxVel>${maxVel}</maxVel>
      <minDepth>${minDepth}</minDepth>
      <fdir1>${fdir1}</fdir1>
    </gazebo>
 
    <gazebo reference="${parent}_to_${name}_wheel_joint}" >
      <!--
     <kp>100000000.0</kp>
     <kd>1.0</kd>
     -->
      <kp>${kp}</kp>
      <kd>${kd}</kd>
    </gazebo>
   
    <!--
   <transmission name="${parent}_to_${name}_wheel_trans">
     <type>pr2_mechanism_model/SimpleTransmission</type>
     <joint name="${parent}_to_${name}_wheel_joint" />
     <actuator name="${name}_wheel_motor">
       <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
       <mechanicalReduction>${reflect * 624/35 * 80/19}</mechanicalReduction>
     </actuator>
   </transmission>
   -->
 
  </xacro:macro>
 
  <!-- off_y = half body + half wheel + 1cm gab between. -->
  <xacro:wheel  
       name="left"  
       reflect="1"  
       parent="main_body_link"  
       length="0.04"  
       radius="0.12"  
       mass="0.242"  
       off_x="0"  
       off_y="${0.11+0.02+0.01}"
       off_z="0"
        role="-${PI/2}"
        pitch="0"
        yaw="0"  
       type="continuous"
       material="l_wheel_mat"  
       Gmaterial="Green"
       mu1="100"
       mu2="100"
       kp="100000000"
       kd="1"
        maxVel="100000000"
        minDepth="0"
        fdir1="0 0 1"
 />
 
  <xacro:wheel  
       name="right"  
       reflect="-1"  
       parent="main_body_link"  
       length="0.04"  
       radius="0.12"  
       mass="0.242"  
       off_x="0"  
       off_y="${0.11+0.02+0.01}"  
       off_z="0"  
       role="-${PI/2}"
       pitch="0"
       yaw="0"
       type="continuous"  
       material="r_wheel_mat"  
       Gmaterial="Red"
       mu1="100"
       mu2="100"
       kp="100000000"
       kd="1"
        maxVel="100000000"
       minDepth="0"
       fdir1="0 0 1"
 />
 
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <!--updateRate>${update_rate}</updateRate-->
      <leftJoint>main_body_link_to_right_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
      <rightJoint>main_body_link_to_left_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
      <wheelSeparation>0.2800</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.2400</wheelDiameter>
      <torque>20</torque>
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
 
</robot>
```

common.urdf.xacro:

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
 
  <!-- Degree-to-radian conversions -->
  <xacro:property name="degrees_45" value="0.785398163"/>
  <xacro:property name="degrees_90" value="1.57079633"/>
  <xacro:property name="PI" value="3.1415"/>
 
  <!-- Some predefined materials/colors -->
  <material name="l_wheel_mat">
    <color rgba="0 1 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="r_wheel_mat">
    <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="tail_mat">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="body_mat">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="tire_mat">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="u_sphere_mat">
    <color rgba="1 0.7 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="l_sphere_mat">
    <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
  </material>
       
  <!-- Null inertial element. This is needed to make the model work with
      Gazebo. -->
  <xacro:macro name="null_inertial">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.001"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.001" iyz="0" izz="0.001"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>
 
  <!-- Inertia of a solid cuboid. Width is measured along the x axis, depth
      along the y axis, and height along the z axis. -->
  <xacro:macro name="solid_cuboid_inertial"
              params="width depth height mass *origin">
    <inertial>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${mass * (depth * depth + height * height) / 12}"
              ixy="0" ixz="0"
              iyy="${mass * (width * width + height * height) / 12}"
              iyz="0"
              izz="${mass * (width * width + depth * depth) / 12}"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>
 
 
  <!-- Inertia of wheel. Height is measured along the z axis,
      which is the wheels's axis. -->
  <xacro:macro name="wheel_inertial"
              params="rad height mass *origin">
    <inertial>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${mass * (3 * rad * rad + height * height)/12}"
              ixy="0" ixz="0"
              iyy="${mass * (3 * rad * rad + height * height)/12}"
              iyz="0"
              izz="${mass * rad * rad / 2}"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>
 
  <xacro:macro name="sphere_inertial" params="radius mass *origin">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${mass}" />
      <insert_block name="origin" />
      <inertia ixx="${2.0 / 5.0 * mass * radius * radius}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
              iyy="${2.0 / 5.0 * mass * radius * radius}" iyz="0.0"
              izz="${2.0 / 5.0 * mass * radius * radius}" />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>
 
</robot>
```

robot.urdf.xacro:

```
<robot name="robot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
 
  <xacro:include filename="$(find description)/urdf/robot/wheel.urdf.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find description)/urdf/robot/body.urdf.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find description)/urdf/robot/common.urdf.xacro" />
 
  <!-- base_link must have geometry so that its axes can be displayed in
      rviz. -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="body_mat"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
  </gazebo>
     
</robot>
```

Could anybody help me with that?

My second problem:

When I drive backwards the rover stutter when the sphere-slider hits the ground after the tail lifted up into the air. The sphere has a friction of mu1=mu2=0 and a stiffness kp=1 mil.

I think this [Video](https://youtu.be/Swx6K2yp6FQ) will explain it.

Would be really nice if anybody could help me with that too.

Thank you and best regards,

F4B1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9463/differential-driven-robot-warping-when-driving-forward-and-stuttering-when-driving-backwards/) by [F4B1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1480/f4b1/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We found the solution:

I made a mistake when I set the origin of the body's and wheel's inertial. I set it to the same offset as I set in the joints but the origin of the inertial is its joint. As it is for the visual and collision. Now I set the origin of each interial to xyz="0 0 0".

In addition we added the axis parameter to the finn's joints and set it to xyz="1 1 1" together with a modification of the joint-type to continuous.

Cheers,
F4B1

---

Originally posted by [F4B1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1480/f4b1/) with karma: 1 on 2015-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0